# jquery find the current data value of class element

Tags: jquery

how to find the current value of data attribute on event click,
when i check the console log it shows undefined.

this is my code down below.

```
<li>
<span class="glyphicon connected" data-connected-node="10"></span>
</li>

<li>
<span class="glyphicon connected" data-connected-node="11"></span>
</li>


 var clickCount = 0;
    $('.connected').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        clickCount++;
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(clickCount == 1) {
                var connectedNode = $(this).attr('data-connected-node');
                console.log(connectedNode); // undefined 
                $('#LoadedEvents').modal({
                    show: true
                });
            }
            if(clickCount > 1) {
                $('#exampleModal').modal({
                    show: true
                });
            }
            clickCount = 0;
        }, 300); // The amount of time between clicks
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.connected').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    clickCount++;
    var connectedNode = $(this).attr('data-connected-node');
    setTimeout(function(connectedNode){
        if(clickCount == 1) {
            console.log(connectedNode); // undefined 
            $('#LoadedEvents').modal({
                show: true
            });
        }
...
```

This might be a scoping problem which should be solved if you pass the attribute value along as a parameter rather than trying to read it inside the timeout handler. I assume `$(this)` will be `undefined` inside your timeout handler function at the point of execution.

Comment: that correct. that why was showing undefined value while execution

Answer (score 0):

Test by pre-declaring the `$(this)` element in a variable and then collecting the value of the attribute from that variable

HTML

```
<li>
     <span class="glyphicon connected" data-connected-node="10"></span>
</li>

<li>
     <span class="glyphicon connected" data-connected-node="11"></span>
</li>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var clickCount = 0;
   $('.connected').click(function(e){
       var thisClass = $(this);
       e.preventDefault();
       clickCount++;
       setTimeout(function(){
           if(clickCount == 1) {
               var connectedNode = thisClass.attr('data-connected-node');
               console.log(connectedNode); // 10 or 11 
               $('#LoadedEvents').modal({
                   show: true
               });
            }
            if(clickCount > 1) {
                $('#exampleModal').modal({
                    show: true
                });
            }
            clickCount = 0;
        }, 300); // The amount of time between clicks
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think as follows:

```
var clickCount = 0;
    $('.connected').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        clickCount++;
       ***var thisNode = $(this);***
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(clickCount == 1) {
                var connectedNode = ***thisNode*** .attr('data-connected-node');
                console.log(connectedNode); // undefined 
                $('#LoadedEvents').modal({
                    show: true
                });
            }
            if(clickCount > 1) {
                $('#exampleModal').modal({
                    show: true
                });
            }
            clickCount = 0;
        }, 300); // The amount of time between clicks
    });
```